# Where clause returns nothing if condition is not met in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, null, case, aggregate-functions, where-clause

This is my query in SS Management Studio

```
    SELECT PersonnelID, Name, EmpStartCalc,
    MAX(PositionDetailsValidFromCalc) PD , 
    Max(PositionHierValidFromCalc) PH, 
    Max(PWAValidFromCalc) Position, 
    Max(RowId) As RowId
    
    FROM TV_IAMintegration_VW
    
    where 
    EmpStartCalc >= 20200101 and
    EmpStartCalc <= 20200131 and
    
    ((20200131 > PositionDetailsValidFromCalc And 
    20200101 < PositionDetailsValidToCalc) or
    PositionDetailsValidToCalc is null)
    
    GROUP BY PersonnelID, Name, EmpStartCalc
```

What I require of this query is to return null in the mentioned columns if "WHERE" clause doesn't successfully meet.

```
MAX(PositionDetailsValidFromCalc) PD , Max(PositionHierValidFromCalc) PH, Max(PWAValidFromCalc) Position
```

and rest of the row should remain as it is.

Comment: Side question, are you storing dates as integers? Why not a date data type?

Comment: Using them as integers to do calculations in PowerApps, in PowerApps we have some limitation over date comparison and calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your `WHERE` (which you need to remove), you need conditional aggregation.

So each `MAX` should go like this:

```
MAX (CASE WHEN
    EmpStartCalc >= 20200101 and
    EmpStartCalc <= 20200131 and
    
    ((20200131 > PositionDetailsValidFromCalc And 
    20200101 < PositionDetailsValidToCalc) or
    PositionDetailsValidToCalc is null)
    THEN whatever_value_you_want_here END)
```